Is there a way to autoplay a instagram reel embed?
<iframe id="instagramEmbed" src="https://www.instagram.com/reel/C6zTuu3s6MB/embed/" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" frameborder="0" width="300" height="600" play>Iframe not supported</iframe>

I want to autoplay this reel Is there a way to do it?
I have tried to put autplay or something like that in the iframe but it dosen't work.

You could do something like this:
document.getElementById("instagramEmbed").onload = function(e) {autoPlay(e)};

And then in the autoPlay function, you can add .click() on the child element with the play button.

It didn't work but thanks anyway bro
